# Is the class which contain __getattribute__ a descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor

In python3's manual:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction
In general, a descriptor is an attribute value that has one of the methods in the descriptor protocol. Those methods are `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()`. If any of those methods are defined for an attribute, it is said to be a descriptor.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        return  object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        return  object.__setattr__(self,attr,value)
```

`__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` are python's magic methods,built-in functions ,`Room` class use magic methods to implement `__get__` and `__set__`,strictly speaking,is the class `Room` a descriptor？

Comment: THAT class does not use magic methods to implement `__get__` and `__set__`.  As long as `getattr` returns something for `__get__`, then it is a descriptor.

Comment: "`Room` class use magic methods to implement `__get__` and `__set__`" - no it doesn't. It doesn't have any implementation of `__get__` or `__set__`. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me, what am I missing? `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` don't "implement `__get__` and `__set__`, so it is really not clear what you are even asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Room` class is not a descriptor. A descriptor in Python is a class that implements at least one of the descriptor methods: `__get__()`, `__set__()`, or `__delete__()`. These methods define how the descriptor interacts with the attributes of the owner object.

In the Room class, the `__getattribute__()` and `__setattr__()` methods are used to intercept attribute access and assignment operations, respectively. However, these methods alone do not make Room a descriptor. They are special methods that are called automatically for every attribute access and assignment, regardless of whether the attribute is a descriptor or not.

To make the class Room a descriptor, you would need to implement at least one of the descriptor methods (`__get__()`, `__set__()`, or `__delete__()`). As it stands, the Room class in your example is simply using the magic methods to handle attribute access and assignment like a regular class, but it doesn't meet the criteria to be considered a descriptor.

To create a descriptor, you need to define one or more of the descriptor methods mentioned earlier, typically within a separate class, and then use an instance of that class as an attribute of another class. The descriptor methods will be called when accessing, setting, or deleting that attribute of the owner object .....by google treanslate

Comment: At the beginning,it is `The Room`,not `he Room`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to "fake" the existence of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__` methods in a would-be descriptor class by implementing a `__getattribute__` method. You can't do it for other special methods, like `__len__` or `__add__` either.

That's because double-underscored names are just a Python-level wrapper around the lower-level slots that are used by the Python interpreter to describe a class's behavior. When a method is assigned to a special name like `__get__` or `__add__`, a corresponding slot in the class structure gets updated so that the interpreter will know to call the method when the relevant language feature (e.g. descriptor behavior, or addition) is invoked on the object. The internal lookup of the method, when that happens, does not go through the `__getattribute__` method. So even if `__getattribute__` tries to provide a `__get__` (or `__add__` or `__len__`) method, it won't work.